# Binary list from indices of ascending integer list

Tags: python, list, binary

I have an ascending list of integers `e` that starts from 0 and I would like to have a binary list `b` whose `i`-th element is 1 if and only if `i` belongs to `e`.

For example, if `e=[0,1,3,6]`, then this binary list should be `[1,1,0,1,0,0,1]`,
where the first 1 is because 0 is in `e`, the second 1 is because 1 is in `e`, the
third 0 is because 2 is not in `e`, and so on.

You can find my code for that below.

**My question is:** is there something built-in in python for that? If not, is my
approach the most efficient?

```
def list2bin(e):
b=[1]
j=1
for i in range(1, e[-1]+1):
    if i==e[j]:
        b.append(1)
        j+=1
    else:
        b.append(0)     
return(b)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with a list comprehension, and in case `e` is huge then better convert it to a `set` first:

```
>>> e = [0, 1, 3, 6]
>>> [int(i in e) for i in xrange(0, e[-1]+1)]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

The `in` operator returns True/False if an item is found in the list, you can convert that bool to an integer using `int`. Note that for lists the `in` is `O(N)` operation, so if `e` is large then converting it to a set will provide you much more efficiency.

Comment: Just a comment, `xrange` doesn't exist in Python3, other than that the solution is beautiful.

Comment: @Ashwini Thank you! Unfortunately I do have to use lists. `e` is not going to be that huge (maximum 150 elements, although later on I may try with around 400), but this will be called over and over, many times (I'm running a reccursive algorithm that will be running for weeks and what I'm asking will be in every iteration). Do you think it makes sense to turn the list into a set every time, in my case?

Comment: @geo909 `timeit` results: searching 400 in a list of size 400 takes 12 micro-seconds, while a set takes just 200 nano seconds.

Comment: @Ashwini Thanks.. And although it's obviously more elegant, your solution is better in terms of effiency, right?

Comment: @geo909 No, the `list` based version is not better than your solution theoretically(as it is an `O(N**2)`) and will be slow for huge lists. But the `set` version will be almost equivalent to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are a built-in way to do that. But you can use [List Comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk%20list%20comprehesions):

```
a = [ 1 if i in e else 0 for i in range(1, e[-1]+1) ]
```

Get fun.