# Efficiently convert list of positions to sequence of binaries for very a large list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very large list of positions (DNA loci) and need to convert it a sequence of binaries.

Example:

Input:

`[3,5] # positions 3 and 5`

Output:

`[0,0,1,0,1] # 1s only for third and fifth positions`

The size of the input list is in the order of millions and the max position is 2.3 billion (the size of the DNA).

Comment: Is the input array always sorted?

Comment: Yes, I can efficiently sort it

Comment: Related: [Binary list from indices of ascending integer list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21409461/7851470)

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy.bincount:

```
a = [3, 5]
b = np.bincount(a) # (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
```

You can ignore the zero-index value by slicing:

```
b = np.bincount(a)[1:] # (0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard python solution:

```py
input_array = [3, 5]
output_array = [1 if i in input_array else 0 for i in range(1,max(input_array)+1)]
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Could you please check the time for this?

Comment: ```python -m timeit -n 1000 "input_array = [i for i in range(0,1000,4)];output_array = [1 if i in input_array else 0 for i in range(1,max(input_array)+1)]"```
1000 loops, best of 5: 2.31 msec per loop

Comment: I guess you can go with numpy bincount as mentioned by @Jan. For larger arrays, numpy works great.

Answer (score 0):

```py
arr = [3, 5]
print([1 if num + 1 in arr else 0 for num in range(arr[-1])])
```

Prints: `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]`